# Which TFS Branch Strategy should be using for this scenario

Tags: tfs, branch

I'm creating a library which is referenced by components in a tree like

Component A -> Componenent B

Component A -> Component C

Component B -> Component C

By branching A into B, and then B into C I can safely complete all my references. But, I ran into a case where the tree was a little more complicated.

Component A -> Componenent B

Component A -> Component C

Component B -> Component C

Component A -> Component D

Component D -> Component C

When I branch D into C, I have two instances of A.

The goal of branching each component is that the solution of C can be checked out with all dependencies in its folder structure, rather than having to check out the solution and external folders which are referenced. Is there a better approach, and or how would I resolve scenario 2?

Comment: Do not use branching for this purpose. That's an old SourceSafe trick which should not be repeated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had a strategy like this and also ran into the same problem you did.

We ended up going back to using a lib folder and checking in built dlls. Yea, you loose a few things, but it is much simpler and we have had no regrets.

Edit: we are now using nuget for this. Highly recommended.

Comment: Thanks, this is what we're moving to.